# How to bind enabled/disabled status to a control instead of view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Usually, I'd bind a status of being enabled/disabled (or visible/hidden/collapsed) to a property in the view model. However, I wonder if there's a smoother way in the particular case with radio buttons.

I have a set of three radio buttons and when I select one of them, I'd like to make a certain text box to become enabled (or visible). When I check another radio button, I wish the text box to become disabled (or hidden).

How do I bind property of a control to a state of another control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=myProperty}
```

You may also need converter

Comment: Oh, that simple? +1 for speediness. I'll try it out immediately.

Comment: np, you can also use RelativeSource to go up by tree until some element type or by level... but anyway I would use ElementName