# Is it neccessary to create a converter for simple true/false operations?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, data-binding

I asked about [binding to a control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33548434/1525840) and learned that I can bind to [ElementName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548492/1525840). So I did. However, I notice that I'll need to revert the value of being selected. Is there a way to do that without a converter?

```
<DatePicker Name="EndDate"
            Text="{Binding Path=EndDate}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=NoEnd,Path=IsChecked}" />
<CheckBox Name="NoEndDate"
          Checked="Checked"
          Unchecked="Unchecked" />
```

I wish to set enabled when the path of *NoEndDate* is false and vice versa.

Comment: So if Checkbox IsChecked=False then DatePicker IsEnabled=True? If you don't want to use a quick inverted boolean converter to throw in the binding base, you could always just use a quick DataTrigger to convert the True to False and vice versa. Is that what you're asking? Generally just a quick converter cuts down on your amount of xaml and makes it quicker/easier to reuse.

Comment: @ChrisW. When you say "*quick inverted boolean converter*" - are you saying a converter as in a class that implemented *Convert(...)* and *ConvertBack(...)* or is there an actual concept of Quick Converter?

Comment: This should help http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: @kenny In what way exactly is it supposed to help? I have quite a few converters, some of them in this very view. They work as supposed to. Am I missing something or did you interpret the questions as "how to use converters"? (If the latter then we misunderstood each other.)

Comment: simple is to just make another of what you know how to do then.

Comment: @kenny I'm assuming that you're trying to help but I simply don't see how that answers my question. Would you kindly elaborate, please?

Comment: Yea so like some folks came in and pointed out, there's the converter way (and no, the "quick converter" wasn't any specific nomenclature, just suggesting it's a quick solution, nothing specific suggested, just semantics so I can understand why you'd ask) which there's tons of examples out there on using an inverse bool converter as a resource. Or you could go the DataTrigger route like qqww2 gave an example of to accomplish the same goal if you wanted pure xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **convert** a boolean value from true to false and vice versa you need a converter, yes. That is exactly what Converters are for in WPF.

I know you are familiar to converters but just to make this post complete, create an InverseBooleanConverter with Convert method like below

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)  
  {  
       if (targetType != typeof(bool) && targetType != typeof(bool?))  
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The targetType must be a bool!");  
       if (value == null)  
            return null;  
       return !(bool)value; 
  }
```

Do the same for the ConvertBack method.

Your XAML code then should look like this:

```
<DatePicker Name="EndDate"
        Text="{Binding Path=EndDate}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=NoEnd, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}“ />
<CheckBox Name="NoEndDate"
      Checked="Checked"
      Unchecked="Unchecked" />
```

Comment: Paste in a **shortened** part of the example and complete it by the XAML part (you may reuse the code I've got in my question, if you'd like. If you do that, I'll accept that as the answer and +1 you too.

Comment: @KonradViltersten satisfying?

Comment: Ecstatic!  +1 and greeny-thingified.    :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom style with a `DataTrigger`. This achieves what you want, but isn't it easier to use converter?

```
<DatePicker Name="EndDate" Text="{Binding Path=EndDate}">
    <DatePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=NoEndDate, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Style>
</DatePicker>
<CheckBox Name="NoEndDate"/>
```

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily need to be a Style Trigger that requires a custom style. Could just do an interaction trigger for the instance as well and leave the style alone.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is

## Yes.

You need a converter whenever you want to bind to something that is not *exactly* the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

XAML has no out-of-the-box support for inline boolean expressions when binding.

A little googling did turn up [QuickConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickConverter/).

Can't say I've tried it, but it should let you [write code like this](http://blog.danskingdom.com/dont-write-wpf-converters-write-c-inline-in-your-xaml-instead-using-quickconverter/):

```
<CheckBox IsEnabled="{qc:Binding '!$P', P={Binding Path=ViewModel.SomeBooleanProperty}}" />
```

Comment: Oh, my. +1 for code joggling but this is - **if** it works - making the code cryptic. Nevertheless, cool to have seen it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Below code will do the work for you. It will enable Button if CheckBox is disabled, and vice-versa. And I use this approach too often as I find it way too easy than using animations and converters.
It uses ChangePropertyAction behavior available in Blend SDK.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,171,147,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=checkBox}">
         <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button2}" PropertyName="IsEnabled"/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
         <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=button2}" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
<Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,145,140,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

Just is case you don't know how to get it work for you :

A. Include following namespaces :

```
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

B. Add references to : `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`, `System.Windows.Interactivity`
On my system these are found in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries`